# Running a jar file on windows mobile

Tags: windows-mobile, java-me

I have a j2me application. I created a jar file and transferred it to a PDA using windows mobile.

But when I click on it trying to execute i get the message:
There is no application associated with "filename". Run the application first, then open this file within the application.

Answer (score 1):

As has been said you will need a Java VM installed on the PDA.

Most HTC devices come with one pre-installed. Java capability for mobile devices is integrated by the device manufacturers. You need to check with your device manufacturer about availability of this in your device.

KVM, the virtual machine for mobile devices, is the counterpart of JVM (Java virtual machine). It is used to run applets and applications written with Java technology on mobile devices. KVM must be installed by the manufacturer. It is NOT available for download or installation by consumers.

**To install .jars on my HTC Touch Diamond I simply copy the .jar file onto the storage card and open it up with File Explorer. The JVM will take you through the install process.**

Without knowing what your device is I cant help much more!

Comment: I don't have a current PDA. I borrowed one from a friend just for testing.
What I am trying to do, is to send requests to a web server.
I made a program in java and I tried to run it on JVM MySaifu, but i get the message that he can not load the Connection class (i got the j2me example from a website, and it works just fine with the simulator).

An alternative would be to use Ajax direct from PDA browser.

Maybe you could suggest me what to choose(from the software point of view), and some devices/PDAs or a good comparison of them in order to achieve the best performance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install a Java VM on your PDA first, so that you can run the jar.

Here's a link to a JVM that runs on Windows Mobile that might work for you:
[Mysaifu JVM](http://www2s.biglobe.ne.jp/~dat/java/project/jvm/index_en.html)

Answer (score 0):

You will struggle to get it running as Windows does not support J2ME app by default. The only way to get it to run is if the windows mobile had J2ME Application Manager installed on it.

From the little work I've done on Mobile developments, most of the devices came with the application manager provided by the handset manufacturer. That said, I would check out the Mysaifu JVM suggested by @jvilalta.